# Mysql connect tables through foreign key, depends from field type

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Mysql database question. There is system with objects(Domains). Each domain has own table. All objects has unique 16 varchar id - guid

```
CREATE TABLE `guid` (   
   `guid` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
   `obj_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `obj_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `actived` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   PRIMARY KEY (`guid`) 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `product` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,    
    /*....*/ 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `catalog` (   
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    /*....*/ 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would like connect table guid(fields: obj_type, obj_id) and domain tables(field:id) through foreign key.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: You first have to change your engine to InnoDB because MyISAM does **not** support foreign keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table. The parent and child tables must both be InnoDB tables. They must not be TEMPORARY tables.

```
CREATE TABLE product 
  ( 
     id   INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id), 
     FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES guid (guid ) 
  ) 
engine=myisam 
DEFAULT charset=utf8;
```

Comment: "FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES guid (guid )" we link product.id and guid.guid it's not exactly what i need. Is it possible connect product.id with (guid.obj_type=product and guid.obj_id )?

Comment: If you define guid.obj_type=product and guid.obj_id  as primary key in GUID table instead of PK on guid column. Then you can define such PK-FK relationship.

Comment: And don't forget to change the storage engine. Defining a FK constraint with MyISAM does nothing.

Comment: Ya, i have written the same in my post related to InnoDB.

Comment: Hm shell i write so in product table:  FOREIGN KEY `constr_product_id_guid_obj_type_obj_id`(id) REFERENCES guid(obj_type ="product",obj_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT?